# Failed importing Oracle VM on Virtualbox

Tags: oracle, macos, virtualbox

I am fairly new to virtualbox and i want to install Oracle Database on my mac but i keep getting this error upon importing to virtualbox

[image]

i tried uninstall and reinstalling the virtualbox but keeps getting the same error can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Go to downloaded link copy down Md5 check sum and verify with `md5` command for the downloaded file,if checksum don't match you need to download again.(most probably you have incomplete or corrupted file).Since import failed I think it's best to download again and verify checksum

e.g Dowloaded OracleBigDatalite as well as md5sum.txt

```
$ cat md5sum.txt
26197c5d1f8e22102dc2f3641a58a851  BigDataLite411.7z.001
91198541deae1925888534ad5bc68e87  BigDataLite411.7z.002
67a2c534d407a18b5193df262173b815  BigDataLite411.7z.003
2da5928c2cca49a8e296a3fc2ef52de0  BigDataLite411.7z.004
ff35b60c518162e9fd4a15c170d53ee1  BigDataLite411.7z.005
970a860bb7e0efacee7a609a1e4d4414  BigDataLite411.7z.006
601927d6910acde33fe1fb377799d4a4  BigDataLite411.7z.007
c6e3763d73217ce7ffc921123f2c7c4b  BigDataLite411.7z.008
b71ed4a3fbd79c269d6fe59e630c0ec1  BigDataLite411.7z.009
f2d25d520719e6d7adea273bf48ec147  BigDataLite411.7z.010
dc6db7a2834022747e0b7aba160e0a23  BigDataLite411.7z.011
ade4d056b6c71912f727eb5f57cc3db6  BigDataLite411.7z.012
$ md5sum BigDataLite411.7z.001   
26197c5d1f8e22102dc2f3641a58a851  BigDataLite411.7z.001
```

First file in downloaded files checksum is matching with md5.txt(md5sum command on Ubuntu WSL on Mac I'm hoping it's `md5`)

P.S:-I don't have enough points to comment